# Cancel button for pop up message before delete not functioning

Tags: javascript, php, html

I've facing problem where, when the confirmation message appear, I click the cancel button, the data will be also deleted. Can someone suggest where need to be fix? Below is the code.

```
echo "<a onClick='myFunction()' href='./delete.php?userID=".$row['userID'] ."'><button>Delete</button></a>";

    <script> 
        function myFunction() {
            $r = confirm("OK to delete?");
            if ($r == false) {
                return false;
                } 
        }
    </script>
```

Comment: You declared JavaScript variable wrongly. You used PHP variable declaration but JavaScript variables are declared with `var`, `let` or `const`.

Comment: Hi. Thanks. I've change the variable but seems like it is still the same. Data will be deleted even when i click cancel.

Comment: @benjamintemitope the dollar sign is perfectly fine in a JS variable name (hello, jQuery!), and even at the very start it doesn't make it a "PHP variable declaration." The keywords you mentioned would change scope / behavior of the variable, but that is not the essential part of the problem here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The anchor tag event has to be prevented when the 'Cancel' is clicked with `event.preventDefault()`.

Example

```html
<a onClick="myFunction()" href="https://google.com">Delete
<script>
   function myFunction() { 
      let r = confirm("OK to delete?"); 
      
      if (r == false) { 
        // It will prevent visit to 'https://google.com'
        return event.preventDefault();
      } 
   }
    
</script>
```

Comment: the code works! Many thanks. May God bless you. Hopefully this will also benefits others!